# How to build kernel module on linaro hikey ARM 64bit board Cortex A53

Tags: module, kernel

I need help compiling a very simple hello world kernel module.  I'm trying to do it without cross compiling rather using the native gcc that is part debian jessie on the board.  Anyone know how to do this?

Below is the simple module:

```
#define MODULE
#define LINUX
#define __KERNEL__

#include <linux/module.h>  /* Needed by all modules */
#include <linux/kernel.h>  /* Needed for KERN_ALERT */

int init_module(void)
{
    printk("<1>Hello world 1.\n");

    // A non 0 return means init_module failed; module can't be loaded.
    return 0;
}


void cleanup_module(void)
{
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Goodbye world 1.\n");
}
```

Comment: Usual kernel module built with `make -C <kbuild-dir> M=<pwd>`. What is a problem with standard approach? BTW, none of *MODULE*, *LINUX* and *__KERNEL__*  macros should be defined by the module: they are set by kbuild.

Comment: So I tried doing standard approach but it seems it is throwing me an error.  I think the issue is that I don't have the full kernel build directory only the headers as I read late last night that the linaro hikey source is not entirely pushed back into mainstream debian distros.  I'm downloading the hikey linaro linux source and will try again to compile my simple kernel module.